# Permanently remove first image from posts

Tags: php, posts, images, themes, filters

I have around 2,500+ posts on my site where I've inserted images using the traditional method into the post content itself.

In upgrading to a different theme, the single post page now displays the featured image as well before the title (which I want to keep), but I now would like to remove the first image from the_content to prevent duplicate images from showing up.

I know that it can be done with this filter, but is there are way to *permanently* remove the first images from my old posts other than manually going through each one?

```
function remove_first_image ($content) {
if (!is_page() && !is_feed() && !is_feed() && !is_home()) {
$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $content, 1);
} return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_first_image');
```

I feel as if this filter might be resource intensive and be very unflexible for things I might wish to do in future within posts.

Another thread mentioned "Export your database tables to your desktop.than you can remove all unwanted tags by using any text editor such as notepad++." but I'm not familiar with how to do that.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Very similar code in a loop could remove the image and resave the post content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just as @s_ha_dum suggests, you can loop through all of your posts and update the content of each one.

The following gives you the idea but is untested:

```
$posts = get_posts( array( 
    'post_type'      => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => 500, 
    'offset'         => 0, 
) );

foreach( $posts as $post ):
    // Update each post with your reg-ex content filter:
    $pid = wp_update_post( array( 
        'ID'           => $post->ID,
        'post_content' => preg_replace( "/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $post->post_content, 1 )
    ) );
    // Show the update process:
    printf( '<p>Post with ID: %d was %s updated</p>', 
        $post->ID, 
        ( 0 < $pid ) ? '' : 'NOT' 
    );     
endforeach;
```

To avoid PHP timeout, I added a finite number of posts to update with a given offset. You can adjust this to your needs. It's best to try it first on a single post while you're testing it.

But **remember to backup your database before testing this**!

### Demo Plugin - First Image Remover

Here's a demo plugin with a custom admin page:

[image: Admin page]

and it's own admin menu item:

[image: Admin menu]

You can create a plugin file `/wp-content/plugins/first-image-remover/first-image-remover.php` with the following code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: First Image Remover
 * Description: Remove the first image from the post content
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/142494/26350 
 * Version:     0.0.1
 */

/**
 * Create the 'First Image Remover' admin menu
 */

function wpse_142494_create_menu()
{
    // Create new top-level menu:
    add_menu_page( 
        'First Image Remover', 
        'First Image Remover', 
        'manage_options', 
        'wpse_142494_settings_page', 
        'wpse_142494_settings_page'
    );
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'wpse_142494_create_menu');

/**
 * Create the 'Image Replacer' settings pge
 */
function wpse_142494_settings_page()
{ 
?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>First Image Remover</h2>
        <p>Remove the first image of each post in the selected loop.</p>


        <h3>Help:</h3>
        <p>Avialable GET parameters: 
        <pre>
wpse_ppp - Posts Per Page (int), 
wpse_offset - Offset (int),
wpse_update - Update mode (boolean) 

Update Example for 5 posts with offset 10:

/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpse_142494_settings_page&wpse_offset=10&wpse_ppp=5&wpse_update=yes
        </pre>
        <h3>Loop:</h3>
        <?php wpse_142494_loop(); ?>
    </div>
<?php
}

/**
 * Fetch posts based on user input
 */
function wpse_142494_loop()
{
    // Only site admin can update posts:
    if( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) return;

    // Get user input:
    $params = filter_input_array( INPUT_GET, array( 
        'wpse_offset'  => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
        'wpse_ppp'     => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, 
        'wpse_update'  => FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, 
    ) );

    // Fetch posts to update:   
    $posts = get_posts( array( 
        'post_type'      => 'post', 
        'posts_per_page' => ( ! empty( $params['wpse_ppp'] ) )    ? $params['wpse_ppp']    : 10 , 
        'offset'         => ( ! empty( $params['wpse_offset'] ) ) ? $params['wpse_offset'] : 0, 
    ) );

    // Loop through posts:
    $li = '';
    foreach( $posts as $post ):

        if( $params['wpse_update'] ):           
            // Update each post with your reg-ex content filter:
            $pid = wp_update_post( array( 
                'ID'           => $post->ID,
                'post_content' => preg_replace( "/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $post->post_content, 1 )
            ) );

            // Show the update process:
            $li .= sprintf( '<li>%d - <strong>%s</strong> - was %s updated</li>', 
                $post->ID, 
                $post->post_title,
                ( 0 < $pid ) ? '' : 'NOT' 
            );
        else:
            // Show the post list that will be updated
            $li .= sprintf( '<li>%d - <strong>%s</strong> - will be updated</li>', 
                $post->ID,
                $post->post_title
            );
        endif;

    endforeach;

    // Output:
    printf( '<strong>Settings:</strong> Posts: %d - Offset: %d - Update: %s <ul>%s</ul>', 
        $params['wpse_ppp'], 
        $params['wpse_offset'], 
        $params['wpse_update'] ? 'ON' : 'OFF', 
        $li 
    );
}
```

where you can access it from:

```
/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpse_142494_settings_page
```

You can then adjust it to your needs with the following GET parameters:

```
/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpse_142494_settings_page&wpse_offset=10&wpse_ppp=5&wpse_update=no
```

When you run it in the update mode (`wpse_update=yes`) you will get something like:

[image: Update mode]

You can then hopefully extend this and adjust to your needs.

Comment: thanks @birgire ! I understand what posts_per_page does but could you please explain the offset number? Do I copy this code into functions.php?

Comment: @user2803938 I udpated the answer with a demo plugin I created for you. The offset is like paging. Just let me know if you need any assistance to setup the plugin.

Comment: Thanks @birgire! Thats absolutely fantastic. I'll run it on a development server first to see if it does what I want. Thanks for all of your help and all the detail!

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately when i run the plugin it deletes all of the post content complete.

Comment: Thanks for this @birgire , unfortunately when i run the plugin it deletes all of the post content completey rather than just the image. I've changed it to include the following 'post_content' => preg_replace( "<a href[^>]+\><img[^>]+\></a>", "", $content, 1)

Comment: you're welcome. ok, that's strange but one should adjust the regex to ones need, but it worked well on my install. Glad you found the regex that works for you. Here's [a real world example I created](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5dfd3e0f16279db6af7ef2aca8030d53f4e6a149), using the same regex, that removes the first image from the content. Note that this removes only the first `<img>` tag and not the wrapped `<a>` tag. But it's easy to adjust for that, similar to what you used.

Comment: thanks @birgire. I still couldn't get it to work even after changing the code. It deletes all post content including and text below the image still? I know we're close! Any help or tips are appreciated. In the example you provided in that link you output the content again. I don't think you do that in the code of the plugin?

Comment: aha, I think I found a possible bug, for some reason there is `$post->content` instead of `$post->post_content`. I think that could explain it ;-)

Comment: Sorry @birgire I think there is still a problem with this line as it just removes all of the post content? 'post_content' => preg_replace( "/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $post->post_content, 1)

Comment: WOuld it be possible to remove the the <a> tag as well if the image is wrapped in one.

Comment: Thanks for all of your patience @birgire and help with this. Unfortunately after many attempts I can't seem to get it to work. I'm sure it has to do with that particular line. Unfortunately the plugin just removes all content in the posts at the moment.

Comment: I think the problem lies in your modification of the regex. I tested it again with the regex in the current answer and it worked on my install. Then I tested your regex and it removed the content.

Comment: @bigire Thanks so much for your help. I got it working on my live site but for some reason couldn't get it working on my development server. One question, if I increase the ppp above ten it seems to time-out and not update the posts. Is there any way around this? We have over 3,000 posts.

Comment: thanks @bigire  You are a legend. Unfortunately we can't run the script for more than 5 PPP without it timing out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for this, this was an excellent piece of code

Comment: @blogjunkie thank you, glad to hear it was somewhat useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

[Search RegEx](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/) is a good plugin to be able to search and replace (optionally with grep) and save through all posts, pages, excerpts, comments, titles and meta.

Comment: Thanks @Songdogtech but I don't want to replace the first image in each post, will this plugin allow that?

Comment: You can replace with nothing, if you want to delete images and links. Use grep to find the image link and replace with ''.

Comment: sorry I should've said I just** want to replace the first image in each post.