# Always use <figure> for post images

Tags: images, filters, shortcode

The default behavior when it comes to full-width images in posts is this:

- If you insert an image alone, this HTML structure is produced: `<p><img/></p>`
- If you insert an image **with a caption**, the HTML structure is produced: `<figure><img/><figcaption/></figure>`

For the sake of styling (I want to have larger margin around images compared to standard paragraphs), I'd like to get `<figure>` in both cases, not just when there is a caption. How to do it?

**Edit**: one thing I noticed is that the behavior changes as soon as *Visual* and *Text* tabs are switched in the editor, i.e., even before previewing or saving the post. Maybe the correct solution would be to somehow force WordPress editor to always use the `[caption]` shortcode no matter what.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the [`image_send_to_editor`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/image_send_to_editor/) filter:

```
/**
 * Wrap the inserted image html with <figure> 
 * if the theme supports html5 and the current image has no caption:
 */

add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 
    function( $html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt ) 
    {
        if( current_theme_supports( 'html5' )  && ! $caption )
            $html = sprintf( '<figure>%s</figure>', $html ); // Modify to your needs!

        return $html;
    }
, 10, 8 );
```

where you can modify the html of the image when it's inserted into the editor.

I added the check for `current_theme_supports( 'html5' )` in the above filter, to check if you have something like:

```
add_theme_support( 'html5', array( ... ) );
```

in your theme. But you might not want to have this filter callback dependent on your current theme, so you can remove it if you want.

You could also try out the [`get_image_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_image_tag/) filter.

**Update**: Here's the useful unautop function from @bueltge's comment (for better readability):

```
// unautop for images     
function fb_unautop_4_img( $content )
{ 
    $content = preg_replace( 
        '/<p>\\s*?(<a rel=\"attachment.*?><img.*?><\\/a>|<img.*?>)?\\s*<\\/p>/s', 
        '<figure>$1</figure>', 
        $content 
    ); 
    return $content; 
} 
add_filter( 'the_content', 'fb_unautop_4_img', 99 );
```

Comment: That is a great answer. Just a follow up question - adding this `image_send_to_editor` will affect the new posts only, right? If I wanted to also retro-fix the markup in all the historic blog posts, I would probably need to filter the whole post content and find the `<p><img.../></p>` pattern and replace it with figure, right?

Comment: thanks, I hope it will work for you. Yes this will only affect the new inserted images. To modify the old ones, permanently, you might try to modify [this script](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/142494/26350), that I posted earlier, to your needs. You might need to play with the correct regex there. Just remember to backup first ;-)

Comment: If you will use this also for old Posts, then use the filter of content. But as hint, this a  performance break. This source filter the content and change the images in the figure tag. `// unautop for images function fb_unautop_4_img( $content ) { $content = preg_replace( '/<p>\\s*?(<a rel=\"attachment.*?><img.*?><\\/a>|<img.*?>)?\\s*<\\/p>/s', '<figure>$1</figure>', $content ); return $content; } add_filter( 'the_content', 'fb_unautop_4_img', 99 );`

Comment: @bueltge thanks for sharing that un-auto-p function, I'm sure it will be very useful to the OP.

Comment: @birgire Welcome. Maybe you will add this to your answer, is much more readable. Source inside the comments is bad to read.

Comment: Sure, I just added it to the answer. Feel free to edit it if needed @bueltge

Comment: image_send_to_editor works perfectly, thanks. Also a big thanks to @bueltge for the content filter.

Comment: Very nice - thanks!  I decided to use check for `! strstr( $html, '<figure' )` instead of `! $caption` in case they fix this in a future version of wordpress.

Comment: I've been using the `preg_replace` method on `the_content` for a while. Today I noticed that if you have HTML like this: `<p><a href="#">Random link</a> with text</p><p><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></p>` both paragraphs will be wrapped in the `<figure>`. I'm "ok" with reg exp but far from a pro - anyone know how to solve?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question with an accepted answer, but I used the `the_content` version of this answer and in some circumstances it actually fails and wraps more than the image in a figure.

I guess this is the reason one shouldn't parse code using regular expressions.

*So*... I came up with another solution using DOMDocument. It's nowhere near as short as the regexp one but it feel stable:

```
<?php
add_filter('the_content', function ($content) {
    # Prevent errors so we can parse HTML5
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true); # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149180/domdocumentloadhtml-error

    # Load the content
    $dom = new DOMDocument();

    # With UTF-8 support
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218230/php-domdocument-loadhtml-not-encoding-utf-8-correctly
    $dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $content);

    # Find all images
    $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

    # Go through all the images
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $child = $image; # Store the child element
        $wrapper = $image->parentNode; # And the wrapping element

        # If the image is linked
        if ($wrapper->tagName == 'a') {
            $child = $wrapper; # Store the link as the child
            $wrapper = $wrapper->parentNode; # And its parent as the wrapper
        }

        # If the parent is a <p> - replace it with a <figure>
        if ($wrapper->tagName == 'p') {
            $figure = $dom->createElement('figure');

            $figure->setAttribute('class', $image->getAttribute('class')); # Give figure same class as img
            $image->setAttribute('class', ''); # Remove img class
            $figure->appendChild($child); # Add img to figure
            $wrapper->parentNode->replaceChild($figure, $wrapper); # Replace <p> with <figure>
        }
    }

    # Turn on errors again...
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

    # Strip DOCTYPE etc from output
    return str_replace(['<body>', '</body>'], '', $dom->saveHTML($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)));
}, 99);
```

Comment: Do you understand you can be significantly delaying the time it takes to serve the content by doing this?

Comment: Why? Running this code takes basically no time at all.

Comment: Maybe not on a small or test website. But if you're running this code by many users at the same time it will bog down the load time, hindering the performance of the site by at least hundreds of milliseconds.

Comment: IMO, I'd say one would be better off running code 'similar' to this via `wp_schedule_event` and run it on all of the posts' content in the database.

Comment: This is one example stating the inferior performance of DOMDocument, but there are many others and I wouldn't suggest this for a production website
https://blog.futtta.be/2014/05/01/php-html-parsing-performance-shootout-regex-vs-dom/