# Batch process: remove first image from post content

Tags: posts, images, content

I already added a featured post image to all my posts (>1000). Some posts (around 700) still have an image at the beginning of the post content.

Now I need to remove all images which are right at the beginning of the post content. I need to leave the images untouched which are not at the beginning.

Because of that I can't just remove "the first image tag occurrence in the post" because then I would remove images from the post content.

Maybe this plugin here [Permanently remove first image from posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142491/permanently-remove-first-image-from-posts) could be used as a base but what would be re regex or query to reflect this requirements?

Comment: You could check the first html tag from every post content with [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and process your script only if it's an image or a link wrapping an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you haven't modified anything to change the default content output, maybe this can help:

```
add_filter('the_content', function($content)
{
  $content = preg_replace('~^<p><img([^>]+)></p>~i', '', $content, 1);

  return $content;
}, PHP_INT_MAX);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if the first image is repeated elsewhere in the post, all instances will be removed.

Comment: @jgraup Ah, haven't thought about that ;-). I have just updated the answer.

Comment: Hi! 

Thank you! I added this  remove line breaks, white space and non-breaking space only at the start of the post. Maybe you can add that to your answer? 

$clean = preg_replace("/^<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $post->post_content, 1);
$cleaner = preg_replace('/^\s+/', ' ',$clean);
            $moreclean = ltrim($cleaner);
            $cleanest = str_replace("^&nbsp;", "", $moreclean);

            $pid = wp_update_post(array(
                'ID' => $post->ID,
                'post_content' => $cleanest
            ));

Comment: @Marc Hey! I don't quite understand what you're doing but feel free to add your own answer and mark it as a true answer if it's more correct for you. But remember to vote for helpful answers as well. ;-)